# Access an associative array value given an array of keys in PHP

Tags: php, array

I have an object which stores an app configuration in an associative array, as this:

```
[
  'Database' => 
    [
      'DB_SERVER' => 'localhost'
      'DB_NAME' => 'adbname'
      'DB_USER' => 'theuser'
      'DB_PASS' => 'thepass'
    ]
]
```

It could have more than two levels.

And a function, `get()`, which receives a variable number of arguments and returns the configuration value for this parameters. For example, `Config::get('Database','DB_PASS')` will return `'thepass'`.

This is an excerpt of the code:

```
class Config
{
    protected static $values;

    ...

    public static function get()
    {
        $val = &self::$values;
        $argList = func_get_args();
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($argList); $i++) {
            $val = &$val[$argList[$i]];
            if(empty($val)) break;
        }
        return (is_null($val)?"":$val);
    }
}
```

Is there a more elegant / efficient way of accessing the value?

(note: I posted the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37697445/access-an-associative-array-value-given-an-array-of-keys-in-php/37698767#37698767) but I was notified this web was a proper place to ask)

Comment: Do you really need to be able to pass in an arbitrary length list of parameters to this function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code seems fine, but it's a bit verbose. You can make it more elegant with a `foreach` loop, clean up the way you exit the function, and if you're using PHP 5.6 or above you can use a real variable-length argument list. See:

http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list

```
class ConfigurationHandle
{
    protected static $configuration;

    <...>

    public static function get(...$arguments)
    {
        $value = &self::$configuration;
        foreach($arguments as $argument)
        {  
          $value = &$value[$argument];
          if(empty($value)) return "";
        }
        return $value;
    }
}
```

I've written out full words, because there is no need to abbreviate. I think this code is more elegant, because it is easier to read and understand, but it is not more efficient.

It would be more efficient if you dumped the `Config` class altogether, and used a one dimensional array like this:

```
$configuration = ['DATABASE_SERVER' => 'localhost',
                  'DATABASE_NAME'   => 'adbname',
                  'DATABASE_USER'   => 'theuser',
                  'DATABASE_PASS'   => 'thepass'];
```

That is immeasurable more efficient, and might I say it's elegant too?

If top speed is not important to you, but multiple levels, and more control, are, then go for the class.